# Screen turns black while using antd modal

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I have a list of rows in a table. This only happens when i have more rows in a table. I am using modal of antd.
This is my code:

```
import {Modal,Button} from "antd";

 const [isDeleteModalVisible, setIsDeleteModalVisible] = useState(false);
const  handleOk =  (id) => {
    store.dispatch(deleteProductList(id));
    setIsDeleteModalVisible(false);
  };
  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsDeleteModalVisible(false);
  };
<Button
            icon={<DeleteFilled />}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#D15B47",
              color: "#ffffff",
            }}
            onClick={showDeleteModal}
          >
           Delete
          </Button>
          <Modal
            title="Confirm Delete"
            visible={isDeleteModalVisible}
            onOk={() => handleOk(record.id)}
            onCancel={handleCancel}
            
          >
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this vehicle?</p>
          </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on from the content in the question. But I assume that the backdrop has full opacity or a color that has an alpha of 1? Try to inspect the backdrop and see if the color is correct.

Comment: yes i have checked z-index is shows as 1000 but if i decrease it from inspect itself than modal is not visible

Comment: can you see the background color it has? if so maybe add it to your question.